# rails ajax call not working in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I just started to learn ajax implementation with Rails 5.
I am following an article.

For the sake of simplicity I just did scaffold

`rails g scaffold User name:string`

Now I have an option to create a new user.

Currently my **index.html.erb** has

`<%= link_to 'New User', new_user_path%>`

As suggested in the article I added `remote: true`

`<%= link_to 'New User', new_user_path, remote: true %>`

And then in the form I did

`<%= form_for @user, remote: true do |form| %>`

Then I clicked **New User**. I see nothing is happening.

But when I checked terminal, I can see

```
Started GET "/users/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-09-01 00:00:20 +0530
Processing by UsersController#new as JS
  Rendering users/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered users/_form.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (6.4ms)
```

But I dont see any new user form appearing or any ajax action happening. what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to make the `new_user_path` a remote (AJAX) link. You want to render the `new` view (`new.html.erb`) with standard HTML and only use `remote: true` for your form.

So, replace `<%= link_to 'New User', new_user_path, remote: true %>` with `<%= link_to 'New User', new_user_path %>`

Comment: You mean I need to remove `remote: true` from index file ?

Comment: Yes, from your `new_user_path` link. Updated my answer.

Comment: I did. I removed it and retained in form. But its still reloading and going to new url  `http://localhost:3000/users/new`

Comment: You mean when you click "New User" you're redirected to the `new.html.erb` view or you're stuck in the index view? Could you also post your `create` and `new` actions from your `UsersController`?